# Expandable div along with it's content

Tags: html, css

My code is [here on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hitman666/Prjd8/4/)

What I can't accomplish is: if you narow the screen size by axis x, my boxes containing the image of santa will "fall" out of the container box below the first container, which is OK (it's ok that the go below), but I would also like the that the div which contains these images "streches" down as well.

I bet I'm missing something in my css part of the code - can you please advise?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DfLSB/ min-width on the container and they wont fall out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a css only solution: http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/Prjd8/6/

**CSS**

```
.accContent{
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    padding: 5px;
    min-height: 160px;
     border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;

    -moz-border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-bottom-left-radius:5px;

    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:5px;

    -khtml-border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
    -khtml-border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
    overflow:hidden; /* Add This */
}

.okvir{
    width: 210px;
    height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #CCC;
    margin:0 0 20px 20px;/* Modify this to make it look good when resized */
    float: left;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: I remarked your question as the correct answer as it solves this with only two changes to the css file - nice!

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you float some elements the parent of those elements will not take the actual height
so for this you apply a clear fix class for container div of floated elements.

In Css

```
.clearfix:after {  
    clear:both; 
    content:"."; 
    display: block;
    height:0; 
    visibility:hidden;
}

.clearfix {display:inline-block;}
* html .clearfix {height:1%;}
.clearfix {display:block;}
```

In Html

```
<div class="clearfix" >    
    <div class="okvir">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/silent_night_icons/128/santa.png" /><br/>CTA 2</a>
    </div>  

    <div class="okvir">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/silent_night_icons/128/santa.png" /><br/>CTA 2</a>
    </div>  

    <div class="okvir">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/silent_night_icons/128/santa.png" /><br/>CTA 2</a>
    </div>                          
</div>
```